# MEAN.js - How do you insert sub-documents into a mongoose model before saving?

Tags: model, mongoose, document, mean-stack, subdocument

Danger! I'm new to the MEAN stack. I may be using the wrong terms. I have also removed and refactored a lot of code from my example to make my question clearer.

I have a schema with multiple properties, one of which is of [mixed type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed). That mixed type is an array of subdocuments, defined by another schema. This other schema has yet another property of mixed type, containing a yet another array of subdocuments, which is defined by yet another schema.

```
var SubSubSchema = new Schema({ 
    name: { type: String, required: true }, 
    value: { type: Number, required: true } 
});

var SubSchema = new Schema({
            name: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                default: '',
                required: "Name is a required field."
            }
            values: {
                type: [SubSubSchema],
                required: "Value updates must contain values!"
            }
}) ;

var MainSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        required: "Name is a required field."
    }
    history: {
        type: [SubSchema],
        required: "Must have a history."
    }
});

mongoose.model('MainStandard', MainSchema);
```

In my client side controller, I create an instance of MainStandard like so:

```
mainStandard = new MainStandards({
    name: $scope.name,
    history: []
});
```

Now I would like to create and insert the history object...

```
// First create something that follows the SubSchema
var historyEntry = {
    name: "test",
    values: []
};

// Now insert the values from the view that follow the SubSubSchema 
for (factor = $scope.selection.length-1;factor>=0;factor--){

     // only store if selected
     if ($scope.selection[factor].selected == true){

         historyEntry.values.push(
             {factor: $scope.selection[factor].name, value: $scope.selection[factor].value}
         );
    }
}

// Insert the finished historyEntry...
mainStandard.history.push(historyEntry);

// ...and save the finished mainStandard
 mainStandard.$save(function(response) {
        $location.path('main-standards/' + response._id);
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
});
```

When I do this, the server side request looks like this:

```
{ name: 'aoeu',
  history: 
  [ { 
   created: 1433430622745,
   creator: '55706a4ef725840d8e8d5716',
   values: **[Object]**
  } ],
}
```

An object, you say? Well that just wont do. So I do some [searching](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/511) and say to myself, "Self, why don't you push the historyEntry into the mainStandard, then push the values to mainStandard.history.values?"

But that doesn't seem to work either. I get an error in my browser's console saying that mainStandard.history.values doesn't exist. Dismayed, I print it out. I see it right there, in its curly braced, quoted glory! Hmm... but wouldn't that be a JavaScript named array? It would explain why Object shows up above.

How can I populate (this may be the wrong term to use) my model before I save it?

Comment: how do you represent this in the view?